# Whats is the best way to edit all the fields from a filtered datatable?

Tags: data-tables, edit

[image: massive editing]

I need edit all the inputs from the filtered datatable field, and I'm proposing something like the image.

But I would like to know about other experiences

Thanks for your help

Comment: How are you editing the data for one row? Do you show a form?  If you do you could have a check box to apply to all rows.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Each row have an input text, and when the user edit the input text, the value is update with the event onBlur. Then, if the user wants edit all rows, he can edit the input text on the header row. I would like to know if this functionality has been commented before in this page.

Comment: Hello I have not seen it before. But it seems reasonable if the editing is inline, with onblur. It is logical that the entry is at the top of the column. This follows what email clients do to check all with an extra check box in the header so a common pattern.

Comment: Hi, and do you know other ways to edit a set of rows of a datatable?

Comment: A lot of work I have done the rows in the table represent some other object so editing the data has means opening a different form or interface. In your spreadsheet type example I think you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

A way to use filters in defined columns in a table list view is to turn the table headers to filters and apply them accordingly to filter results
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is a good way to filter a datatable. My question was about editing various fields from a filtered datatable at the same time.